# Best solution for a user-inputed list that returns the max value?

Tags: python, list, max

So I want to create a list with different temperatures that the user inputs and then print out the max temp. I used the following solution and it works fine:

```
tempList = []

for i in range(0, int(input("How many temps? "))):
    temp = (float(input("Input a temp: ")))
    tempList.append(temp)

print("Temps are: ", tempList, "and the max temp is:", max)
```

However, I am trying to do this with another solution by looping the list:

```
tempList = []

for i in range(0, int(input("How many temps? "))):
    temp = (float(input("Input a temp: ")))
    tempList.append(temp)

print(max(tempList))

max = 0.00

for temp in range(0, len(tempList)):
    if temp > max:
        max = temp
        
print("Temps are: ", tempList, "and the max temp is:", max)
```

It works fine until the end when it prints out "max". It gives me 2 when I input 36.5 or something similiar. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use builtin function names as variable names
2. You are itterating over the indexes of the list
3. There is a builtin function `max` you can use for this

```py
tempList = []

for i in range(0, int(input("How many temps? "))):
    temp = float(input("Input a temp: "))
    tempList.append(temp)
        
print("Temps are: ", tempList, "and the max temp is:", max(tempList))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Which variable name do you mean I'm using that there is a function for? Sorry for stupid questions, I'm really new when it comes to programming.

Comment: `max` is already a builtin function and you were setting `max = 0.00` thus overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
temperatures= []

for i in range(0, int(input("Enter Number of Temperatures You Want to Input: "))):
   temp = (float(input("Enter Temperature: "))) 
   temperatures.append(temp)

print(f"Temperatures You Entered {temperatures}\nMaximum Temperature:",max(temperatures))
```